# Pagination in jqgrid with loadonce?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jqgrid

I know I can set the loadonce flag for jqgrid and it will locally cache the data from the database.  Can one paginate through the data if it is loaded once?  OR do I still need to load each individual page using the 'limit XXX' feature assuming I am getting the data from a MYSQL/php script?

Answer (score 0):

@WildBill
jqGrid LoadOnce demo suggest that it is possible.
Check it with firebug. LoadOnce paging does not trigger server request!